# Set parameter value with CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS always comes out to 0

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, case

I have a parameter (`@noMatch int output`) which I assign a value to based on the `CASE` found in my stored procedure below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_trips_non_aggregate_insert]
     @trips u_trips_non_aggregate readonly, 
     @rowCount int OUTPUT, 
     @noMatch int OUTPUT
WITH RECOMPILE
AS
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[trips_non_aggregate]
        ([LøyvehaverID], [KjøretøyID], [Ordrenummer], [c], [År], [Måned], [Betaling (brutto)], [Betaling (netto)], [LøyvehaverFakturaID], [IsProcessed], [RowIsChecked])
        
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            [LøyvehaverID], [KjøretøyID], [Ordrenummer], [c], [År], [Måned], [Betaling (brutto)], [Betaling (netto)], [LøyvehaverFakturaID], [IsProcessed], [RowIsChecked]
        FROM 
            @trips AS o
        WHERE 
            [IsProcessed] = '0'
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT [Ordrenummer]
                            FROM [dbo].[trips_non_aggregate] AS i
                            WHERE i.[Ordrenummer] = o.[Ordrenummer])

        SET @rowCount = @@ROWCOUNT

        SET @noMatch = 
            CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS
                (SELECT [LøyvehaverID]
                    FROM [dbo].[trips_non_aggregate] AS i
                    INNER JOIN [license_holder] AS o ON i.[LøyvehaverID] = o.[Foretaksnavn])
            THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END

    UPDATE [dbo].[trips_non_aggregate]
    SET [Betaling (netto)] = (SELECT [Betaling (brutto)] / ([MVAsats] / 100 + 1)
                              FROM [tblMVAkoder]
                              WHERE [ID] = 'MVAkode2')

    UPDATE [dbo].[trips_non_aggregate]
    SET [RowIsChecked] = (SELECT [RowIsChecked] = 0)

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

So that when I insert to my database, I am able to flag any entry into `ColumnA` that does not already exist in `ColumnB`. But when I test with fake data, the outcome is always `0`.

Why could that be?

This is how I check its value in C#:

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@noMatch"].Value) == 1) 
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Try an Left Outer Join which compares when you have a null match.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins?force_isolation=true

Comment: SQL has a syntax error; please include the full SQL. Also show the C# where you call the proc and declare the parameters. Use something other than 0 in the SQL temporarily; 0 is default value for an int and could confuse debugging efforts (if you see 0 - is it C# default or really from the DB?)

Comment: This seems weird. Are you routinely emptying the trips_non_agg table? You're accepting a table var, and inserting potentially multiple records to trips_non_agg, but only returning one value in noMatch based on whether any row from trips_non_agg is paired with any row in licence_holder? If there is ever at least a single row in tna that matches lh, this noMatch will forever return 0

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks for that, I did change `0` to `1`, and now it did come out as `1` - that is, it did not detect the data it was supposed to. I have now included my entire stored procedure in my question.

Comment: Did you intend to perhaps join the `@trips` var to licenceholder? As is, any LH row that matches TNA, even if it was inserted 20 years ago, ensures that noMatch is set to 0

Comment: @CaiusJard your previous comment did embarrass me, as that is of course the case.
I should have understood that long time ago.
"If there is ever a single row that matches lh, this noMatch will forever return 0"
How can I bypass that?

Comment: Depends what you're trying to do.. If you want some flag like "at least one of the rows you sent in `@trips` has no matching row in licence_holder" then you'll need to base the query on `@trips`. Perhaps `SET @noMatch = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT null FROM @trips t WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT null FROM license_holder lh WHERE t.[LøyvehaverID] = lh.[Foretaksnavn])) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Comment: Does the join of a Company Name onto an Licensee ID value work? i.e.: `INNER JOIN [license_holder] AS o ON i.[LøyvehaverID] = o.[Foretaksnavn]`

Comment: @CaiusJard I basically want a full stop. I'm checking for companies, that the ones being inserted has already been entered into the personnel part of the app.  So I want the operation to stop (by whichever hacky mean necessary - right now I'm just emptying the `ItemsSource` of the DataGrid and removing the entries from the DB). I did try now to change `[trips_non_aggregate]` to `@trips`, my UserDefinedTableType, but it made no difference. How can I check if there's ANY data being inserted that does not already exist in the joined table?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I understand why you would point that out, it's just a non-optimal named column. It's not actually an ID per se, `LøyvehaverID` is the full company name, just like in `Foretaksnavn`.

Comment: *How can I check if there's ANY data being inserted that does not already exist in the joined table?* You mean, "not to do the insert at all if one or morerecords from @trips has no matching record in licence_holder"? Perhaps `IF EXISTS (SELECT null FROM @trips t WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT null FROM license_holder lh WHERE t.[LøyvehaverID] = lh.[Foretaksnavn])) THEN THROW 51000, 'One of the records being inserted does not have a licence holder record', 1`

Comment: Thinking about it again, I'm a bit confused by what you're asking - you seem to be saying you don't want to insert into TNA if there is a TNA+LH record but you do want to insert into TNA if there is either a "LH but no TNA" or "TNA but no LH" - is it right?

Comment: Indeed, it sounds like you need to check first and `throw`, rather than check the rowcount afterwards

Comment: Good idea: not doing the insert at all would be more optimal. I want to stop the insert and notify the user if: The user is trying to insert data into [trips_non_aggregate].[LøyvehaverID], that does not already exist in [license_holder].[Foretaksnavn]. My method is the user adding a Excel sheet, and this would be one of the safety checks.
I am not familiar with `THROW 51000` message, and how to get it into my C# code (but that I can hopefully figure out).

Comment: @CaiusJard WHAT?? It worked... Thank you so much. And the 51000 message just popped up in my app, too. I have no idea how but I like it.
I am so positively surprised. lol.
Post it up as an answer so I can credit you??

Comment: One moment.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're doing some kind of preflight checking so that you don't insert any data at all from the batch, if one or more incoming `u_trips_non_agg` records don't have a Licence Holder. We can check before we do the insert:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_trips_non_aggregate_insert]
     @trips u_trips_non_aggregate readonly, 
     @rowCount int OUTPUT
WITH RECOMPILE
AS

    IF EXISTS (
      SELECT null FROM @trips t 
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT null FROM license_holder lh WHERE t.[LøyvehaverID] = lh.[Foretaksnavn]
      )
    ) 
      THROW 51000, 'At least one of the records being inserted does not have a related licence holder record', 1;
    


    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[trips_non_aggregate]
        ([LøyvehaverID], [KjøretøyID], [Ordrenummer], [c], [År], [Måned], [Betaling (brutto)], [Betaling (netto)], [LøyvehaverFakturaID], [IsProcessed], [RowIsChecked])
        
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            [LøyvehaverID], [KjøretøyID], [Ordrenummer], [c], [År], [Måned], [Betaling (brutto)], [Betaling (netto)], [LøyvehaverFakturaID], [IsProcessed], [RowIsChecked]
        FROM 
            @trips AS o
        WHERE 
            [IsProcessed] = '0'
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT [Ordrenummer]
                            FROM [dbo].[trips_non_aggregate] AS i
                            WHERE i.[Ordrenummer] = o.[Ordrenummer])

        SET @rowCount = @@ROWCOUNT

        SET @noMatch = 
            CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS
                (SELECT [LøyvehaverID]
                    FROM [dbo].[trips_non_aggregate] AS i
                    INNER JOIN [license_holder] AS o ON i.[LøyvehaverID] = o.[Foretaksnavn])
            THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END

    UPDATE [dbo].[trips_non_aggregate]
    SET [Betaling (netto)] = (SELECT [Betaling (brutto)] / ([MVAsats] / 100 + 1)
                              FROM [tblMVAkoder]
                              WHERE [ID] = 'MVAkode2')

    UPDATE [dbo].[trips_non_aggregate]
    SET [RowIsChecked] = (SELECT [RowIsChecked] = 0)

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

An EXISTS returns true or false depending on whether the query returns any row. It doesn't matter what data is selected; all EXISTS cares about is whether there is any row or not. You can conceive that it stops as soon as it finds one, so it can be quite optimal to not run a massive million rows query just to know if there is one row or not

We actually use it twice, an inner and an outer:

```
  SELECT null FROM @trips t 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT null FROM license_holder lh WHERE t.[LøyvehaverID] = lh.[Foretaksnavn]
  )
```

The first one to run conceptually in the inner one:

```
SELECT null FROM license_holder lh WHERE t.[LøyvehaverID] = lh.[Foretaksnavn]
```

This is coordinated with the outer one, and you could conceive it working like:

```
For `t.[LøyvehaverID]` = 1
SELECT null FROM license_holder lh WHERE 1 = lh.[Foretaksnavn]

For `t.[LøyvehaverID]` = 2
SELECT null FROM license_holder lh WHERE 2 = lh.[Foretaksnavn]
```

And so on; it's basically, for every row in the outer table `@trips` checking if there is a row in in `licence_holder` such that `@trips.[LøyvehaverID]` equals `licence_holder.[Foretaksnavn]`.

If there *is* a row, then `null` is returned. If there *is not* a row, then 0 rows are returns, and that's what NOT EXISTS picks up on. In other words, this structure:

```
  FROM @trips t 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT null FROM license_holder lh WHERE t.[LøyvehaverID] = lh.[Foretaksnavn]
  )
```

will find all `@trips` rows that do not have a matching `licence_holder` row

---

All that is wrapped in another EXISTS, which effectively stops looking as soon as at least one case of "a @trips row that doesn't have a licence_holder row" is found

In total this:

```
EXISTS (
  SELECT null FROM @trips t 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT null FROM license_holder lh WHERE t.[LøyvehaverID] = lh.[Foretaksnavn]
  )
)
```

means:

*there exists a row in @trips where there does not exist a matching row in licence holder*

---

And then we key off of that to throw an exception if it is the case

Comment: Thank you for going above and beyond and giving me such a detailed answer. It works - and your explanation taught me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Is parameter direction configured like

```
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@noMatch", SqlDbType.Int);  
    cmd.Parameters["@noMatch"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Comment: This isn't the problem: *I did change 0 to 1, and now it did come out as 1*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).